# How to linearize following constraint to be used in a MILP model?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linearization

Regarding a project I am currently working on I need to linearize following conditon such that it can be used in a linear optimization model. The condition is:

If $X \geq B$ then $Y=X-B$ ; else $Y=0$.

In this condition both $Y$ and $X$ are decision variables whereas $B$ is a constant.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce two binary variables $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ constrained to sum to $1$. Then model that $\delta_1$ implies $(X\geq B, Y+B-X=0 = 0)$ and $\delta_2$ implies $(X\leq B, Y = 0)$

The implications are modelled using standard big-M models

$$
X \geq B -M(1-\delta_1), -M(1-\delta_1) \leq Y+B-X \leq M(1-\delta_1)\\
X \leq B + M(1-\delta_2), -M(1-\delta_1) \leq Y \leq M(1-\delta_1)\\
$$

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I forgot to mention some critical information namely that $Y$ negativily affects the objective function and is restricted to take on non negative values. It seems this simple constraint : $Y>=X-B$ does the trick in this case. Because when $(X-B)>=0$ then $Y=(X-B)$ and when $(X-B) <0$ then $Y=0$. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: You can add what ever extra constraints you want, it doesn't impact the model, although some constraints might get redundant.

Comment: I understand that. But I meant to ask whether the single constraint I posted in the previous comment could replace your constraints.

Comment: You cannot remove the binaries unless you for example have a model which is convex graph-representable.  One such case could be that you actually want $Y$ to model max(0,X-B), and this term enters with a positive sign in a minimization. Then your epigraph model is simply $X-B\leq Y$, no need for binary variables.